# Jsp tag for file download or save file?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee

From my JSP page I should be able to click on a button which will open the widget to perform file save option. Looks like input tag with type=”xxxx” can be used for file upload. I need to be able to download or save a file. Is there something available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send the response from server with header

> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="yourfilename.ext"

Then just put `<a>` tag in your page with `href =` url which serves the file with required response header.

Comment: i believe you suggesting me to use.. Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName); .... apart from this.. did we have any predefined custom tag.. which we can directly use in JSP...

Comment: This would be the best way to do it!